# Rspec testing Belongs to and has many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, associations

I'm running a rspec test to make sure that two models are associated between each other with `has_many` and `belongs_to`. Here is my test below.

```
describe "testing for has many links" do
  before do
    @post = Post.new(day: "Day 1", content: "Test")
    @link = Link.new(post_id: @post.id, title: "google", url: "google.com")
  end

  it "in the post model" do
    @post.links.first.url.should == "google.com"
  end
end
```

The test is telling me that url is an undefined method. What's wrong with my test? Or did I just miss something basic.

The model file for Post

```
has_many :links
```

The model file for Link

```
belongs_to :post
```

On top of that, the link model has the attribute `post_id`

Comment: Why test the functionality of ActiveRecord, and not the functionality of the application that depends on Active Record?

Comment: That's a good point. Should I then just test for a method that uses the methods from associations between the models?

Comment: You should write integration tests for your application and make sure that it does the things it needs to do. When you have some complex low-level logic, then test that using unit tests.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to save both models to validate this relationship, also, you can use [shoulda](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda) gem.

The code looks like:

```
describe Link do
  it { should belong_to(:post) }
end
```

---

```
describe Post do
  it { should have_many(:links) }
end
```

Comment: Couple of years later I'm coming here just to mention that if you want to test it, you are testing the Rails framework. It's a useless test. I'm not doing this anymore ;)

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign your `link` to your `post` otherwise, if you do `@post.links`, you will get a empty array ([]), which `[].first` returns `nil`. Then your try `nil.url` and then you get *url is an undefined method for `NilClass`*.

```
@post = Post.new(day: "Day 1", content: "Test")
@link = Link.new(title: "google", url: "google.com")
@post.links << @link
```

Comment: Would my updated code in the question work as well? That was the original code I had, I just missed adding `post_id: @post.id`.

Comment: Since you only do `new`, your object are not saved. So when you do `@post.links`, the program will try to load those `links` from the database. You don't have no saved ones so it will be empty.